# How to change input types in existing form using Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

I've got form class where I'm defining some inputs, something liek this:

```
class User extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mail', 'text', array('label' => 'Mail'))
                ->add('password', 'text', array('label' => 'Hasło'))
                ->add('description', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Opis'));
    }
}
```

I want to change mail and password input type to readonly and set them some values.
Now, I use form this way:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new User($this->get('database_connection')));
```

I tried many things, but Symfony2 has so many Form classes and I've lost in that.
I want to simply add some atributes to existing, added inputs.
I don't use Doctrine2 ORM, I use Doctrine DBAL, if it does matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not display a password anyway and store it encrypted in your database.

Comment: @fdomig This is admin panel to script, whose login at other site so I must store it unhashed, encryption here is overkill ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your can set default value with 'data' parameter and readonly with attr parameter

```
$builder
    ->add('mail', 'text', array('label' => 'Mail', 'data' => 'Default value'
           attr => array('readonly=>'readonly')));
```